# Update xml column in a table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need to remove a Xml element which has the attribute of `A` with the value of `xxxx` from the Xml values in a column.

Method 1:

```
update t set x = x.query('//E[@A != "xxxx"]')
```

Method 2:

```
update t set x.modify('delete /E[@A = "xxxx"]')
```

Which one is better?

Comment: The intention is more clear in the second one, so for maintenance reasons I'd choose that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both calls would not do the same:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
  <test pos="1" a="xxx">test 1</test> 
  <test pos="2" a="SomeOther">test 2</test> 
  <test pos="3" a="xxx">test 3</test>
  <OtherElement>This is another element</OtherElement> 
  </root>';
```

--Try this with either this approach

```
SET @xml=@xml.query(N'//test[@a!="xxx"]')
```

--Or try it with this

```
SET @xml.modify(N'delete //test[@a="xxx"]')

SELECT @xml;
```

The result of the first is

```
<test pos="2" a="SomeOther">test 2</test>
```

While the second returns

```
<root>
  <test pos="2" a="SomeOther">test 2</test>
  <OtherElement>This is another element</OtherElement>
</root>
```

**XML is not stored as the text you see**. It is stored as a tree structure representing a complex document. To *modify* this is fairly easy, just kick out some elements. The `query()`approach has to rebuild the XML and replace the first with an new one. So my clear advise is: Use the `modify()`approach! If you are really good with `XQuery` and `FLWOR` the `query()` approach is much mightier, but this is another story...

Comment: Agree. In my case there is no root XML element and there is only one element (in your example, there will be only elements of "test"). So I was focus on the performance difference.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 About *I was focus on the performance difference* I'd suggest to read [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) :-D